# File not getting uploaded at server

Tags: ajax, html

I am getting this following error. i am trying to upload the file to the server.can somebody please suggest something

Error - Failed to load resources: The server responded with a status of 405 method not allowed

```
        </article>
        <script>
            function sendFileToServer(formData,status)
            {
                var uploadURL ="http://localhost/upfile/file/"; //Upload URL
                var extraData ={}; //Extra Data.
                var jqXHR=$.ajax({
                        xhr: function() {
                        var xhrobj = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                        if (xhrobj.upload) {
                                xhrobj.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                                    var percent = 0;
                                    var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                                    var total = event.total;
                                    if (event.lengthComputable) {
                                        percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                                    }
                                    //Set progress
                                    status.setProgress(percent);
                                }, false);
                            }
                        return xhrobj;
                    },
                url: uploadURL,
                type: "POST",
                contentType:false,
                processData: false,
                    cache: false,
                    data: formData,
                    success: function(data){
                        status.setProgress(100);

                        $("#status1").append("File upload Done<br>");         
                    }
                }); 

                status.setAbort(jqXHR);
            }
```

Comment: I'm fed up with looking at loads of code that has nothing to do with the issue. Cut it right back to the core of the issue. You'll probably see the answer, but if you don't, someone else probably will without having to read through a load of css and other irrelevant stuff - unless it's something like a stray quote or something in that, in which case you'll fix it yourself easily.

Comment: @Nick .. sorry for late reply .. can you please check it again... i uploaded the whole file so that anyone can run the file... thanks in advance

Comment: The server error logs should be able to tell you more.

Comment: contentType=false? See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST'

make sure you check your contentType